# update a specific field on all rows of a table with about 50000 records

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that holds my users information like username , password , name , family , etc. already when a user register in my site her password hashes with one md5() function then insert into table. my table have about 50000 records now.
but now i want to hash their passwords with two md5() function again for security issues. for that i write below code that first selects all of the users and then execute a update Query for change passwords:

```
$allMembers =   mysql_query("select `username`,`password` from `members`",$conn);


if (mysql_num_rows($allMembers) > 0){

    while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($allMembers)){

            $oldPass    =   $row['password'];

            $newPass    =   md5(md5('Hello'.$oldPass.'Friends'));

            mysql_query("update `members` set `password`='$newPass' where `username`='".$row['username']."'",$conn);
    }
}

echo("Yes");
```

but when i run this code It took very little and produce **No Data Received message**.
but now how i update the password field in my large table ?

**Edit** :i was used salt + md5 but removed it in my code for Summarization :)

Comment: "two md5() function again for security issues."... WTF! Don't go down this road. Read about password salting to make passwords more secure, not hashing several times (which generally makes passwords __less__ secure)

Comment: have you checked if select query returning anything or not ?

Comment: This will triple-md5 those passwords, since you're running `md5(md5($password_md5_hash))`. Anyway, MD5 was meant to be fast, you [should be using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110196/php-net-says-that-md5-and-sha1-unsuitable-for-password) a truly hard to crack algorithm that is meant for passwords.

Comment: have you any better suggestion?

Comment: As Mark said, running two hashes won't help at all. First choose a better hash algorithm, then salt the passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run it as a single query:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `password`=MD5(MD5(`password`))
```

BTW double MD5 is useless. you can MD5 + salt or  SHA1 + salt if you want better security.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: is There a difference between md5() php function and MD5() mysql function ?

Comment: @Ahmad - there is no difference between an MD5 hash generated using PHP and one generated using MySQL, but please (for the sake of your security) don't do this. And while you're at it, mysql is out of date, consider mysqli or pdo instead for your database access