# What Does This Piece Of PHP do? (password decryption)

Tags: php, passwords, md5, sha1, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I md5(sha1(password))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143101/can-i-md5sha1password)

```
$pass = md5($_POST["pass"].sha1($_POST["pass"]))
```

I saw this somewhere and was confused. Does this read a password and decrypt it using sha1 then md5 or reverse? Or is there some other things that I'm missing?

Comment: `.` concatenates strings in PHP.

Comment: It offers the illusion of securely hashing a password, while failing to securely hash the password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I md5(sha1(password))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143101/can-i-md5sha1password) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110196/php-net-says-that-md5-and-sha1-unsuitable-for-password

Comment: @user1115155 - Please don't do that... The post will be closed by the community.  There is no need to "vandalize" your posts.  Trust the site :)

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since you practically deleted your post.

Comment: @sha - for the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12309836/2) :P

Comment: Please don't vandalize/remove posts. People may have the same question someday. Also, don't re-post it.

Answer (score 11):

It is hashing `$_POST['pass']` with the `sha1` algorithm, then combining that hash with `$_POST['pass']`, then hashing the resulting combined string with the `md5` algorithm.

Why, I have no idea.

Answer (score 5):

What it is doing is that it is concatenating the password with the sha1 hashed version of it (one of these is the salt) then hashing it into an MD5 value.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it hashes the password.

It concatenates the clear password with the sha1'd password. Then it Md5 the whole thing

Comment: Encryption can be reversed. This can't, so it's a hashing, not an encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It hashes it with MD5.

Takes your password from the form, adds a salt and hashes the whole thing.

**Note:**

The 'salt' is a another hash. It is **not a good idea** to do it this way, a salt should be a *random value* that you have made that keeps the password secure.

Comment: Not sure why someone would vote down a correct answer? Hmm

Comment: I did not, but now I do. You have mistaken a salt with a custom hashing function. As I said, -1 now.

Comment: No they are hashing the password and using that as a salt. They are salting the raw password with a hashed version of the raw password then hashing the whole thing with MD5. So not incorrect. You say tomato I say Tomahto... Still all the same thing

Comment: If you interpret it that way, it makes more sense. But still, if you consider whole md5($x.sha1($x)) thing as my_hash($x), there is no salt, just a custom hashing function. What I would call a salt is something external, not replicable on the basis of the value we are hashing. See the explanation eg. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: I didn't say it was a good salt lol.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)): '... a salt consists of random bits, creating one of the inputs to a one-way function. The other input is usually a password or passphrase.' A hashed password is **not** a salt.

Comment: Sticking to my guns. I think the dev who wrote that line of code was using it as a salt. Not saying it's right just saying that's what the dev was probably doing. Hate me if you will.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Okay, I get your point.

Comment: Thanks. And actualy a good salt would be random bits but sadly a lot of devs use the same salt that is hardcoded or so on thinking just cuz they added it, the password is more secure. Anywho peace love world peace whatever I'm out. :)

Comment: @AlexReynolds You have to use a hard-coded salt, but ideally it would be different for each installation of the application (e.g. phpMyAdmin).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16396/discussion-between-alex-reynolds-and-shaquin-trifonoff)